# Remove the autogenerated row with aggregated values when creating a table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a table consisting of four StoreKeys and its corresponding values by Importing a DataSet using a MDX Query and subsequently created a table in SSRS.

The table looks like this:

```
StoreKey  Sales  %
          500   50 %
   1111   125   12.5 %
   1100   125   12.5 %
   1133   125   12.5 %
   1114   125   12.5 %
```

where the latter column is an expression which is implemented as:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total_Price.Value)/SUM(fields!Total_Price.Value,"DataSet4")
```

,i.e. I want to calculate how much each store contributed to the total sale during the period as a percentage.

My issue is however, that since the Row Before `StoreKey = 1111` is added, it uses that row as well in the calculations, rendering my solution to become vastly inaccurate.

Does anyone have a trick for solving this?

Regards,

Cenderze

EDIT: After snowlockk's comment I've tried the following:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total_Price.Value)/ReportItems!Textbox57.value
```

as the expression, this however gave me #ERROR on every row. My initial though was that Textbox57 may be 0, but it was not.

Comment: You want percentage of group sales? get the value of group sales from ReportItems!TextboxName.value as your SUM(fields!Total_Price.Value,"DataSet4" in.=Sum(Fields!Total_Price.Value)/SUM(fields!Total_Price.Value,"DataSet4")

Comment: @Snowlockk     Interesting approach, gonna look into that. At the moment I don't have any Group at all, this extra line just came along when I created the table.

Comment: @Snowlockk     Thanks for a nice reply, I've edited my post to reflect what has happened now.

Comment: Add a group on StoreKey. Make the 500 cell under sales Sum(Fields!Total_Price.Value) and then use the textbox for the percent calc.

Comment: @Snowlockk     How do you mean? I've made a Group under StoreKey , but that resulted in the same table. table as earlier. I also tested adding a "Add total after", but that one calculated with my excess row as well resulting in a double as high total.

Comment: @Snowlockk     Feel free to add your suggestion to use `ReportItems` in an answer and I'll accept that. What I did was to alter the MDX Query which imported the data set, but I still used `ReportItems` to do the calculation in SSRS which I was not aware of existed until your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to include the data rows that have a blank StoreKey field from your current solution.

You can use an **IIF** to check for them and use 0 instead.

```
=Sum(Fields!Total_Price.Value) / SUM(IIF(Fields!StoreKey.Value = "", CDEC(0), Fields!Total_Price.Value),"DataSet4")
```

I am assuming that your Price is a decimal - if it's an integer, you wouldn't use the **CDEC** to convert then zero to decimal.

Comment: You may need to make that IIF(Fields!StoreKey.Value = "" OR IsNothing(Fields!StoreKey.Value),...